# What could cause an assignment to not work?

Tags: c#, enums, variable-assignment

I am working on a project in C#, and for some reason, when I try to assign a value to an enum variable, the assignment does not happen.  I would copy my code, but it is really just a simple assignment.  It's something like:

```
testVar = MyEnum.TYPE_OF_ENUM;
```

where `testVar` is of type `MyEnum`. When I step through this line using the VisualStudio debugger, I can see that the value of `testVar` does not change.  What could possibly make an assignment fail like that?

EDIT:

Ok I will provide more context.

```
public enum MyEnum1
{
    ONE,
    TWO,
    THREE,
    FOUR,
    FIVE,
    SIX,
    SEVEN,
    EIGHT
}

public enum MyEnum2
{
    A,
    B,
    C,
    D,
    E,
    F
}

public void StateMachine(MyEnum1 state1)
{
    if(state2 == MyEnum2.A)
    {
        switch (state1)
        {
            case MyEnum1.ONE:
                state2 = MyEnum2.B;
                MyFunc(MyEnum2.B);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    else if (state2 == MyEnum2.B)
    {
        switch(state1)
        {
            case MyEnum1.ONE:
                state2 = MyEnum2.B;
                MyFunc(MyEnum2.B);
                break;
            case MyEnum1.THREE:
                state2 = MyEnum2.C;
                MyFunc(MyEnum2.C);
                break;
            default:
                break;                
        }
    }
    // Etcetera
}
```

The failure occurs on the `state2 = whatever` assignments. (state2 is a field, not a property)

Comment: If you could post your enum definition that woudl help.

Comment: Can you add a bit more context to the question? maybe the definition of the enum and the definition of the testVar including (private, public qualifiers)

Comment: Have you looked at the value of both `testVar` and `MyEnum.TYPE_OF_ENUM` before **and** after the assignement?  Can you give some more context?

Comment: The assignment seems to work most of the time. Only in else if section under `case MyEnum1.ONE:` does it fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is MyEnum.TYPE_OF_ENUM the first value in the enum, or is TYPE_OF_ENUM assigned to a integer value of 0?

A non-initialized enum will be set to 0, so it may already match.

Otherwise, it is much more likely that you have something else going on that you haven't noticed yet.

Comment: That's a good thought, although it was not the case in this situation.

Comment: You were right, it was something that I hadn't noticed.  Turns out that an Exception was getting thrown deep in MyFunc because of threading issues and handled in a way that changes state2.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is property with a broken setter:

```
class C
{ 
    private MyEnum foo = MyEnum.Something;
    public MyEnum Foo 
    {
        get { return foo; }
        set { }
    }

    void DoSomething()
    {
        Foo = MyEnum.SomethingElse; // does nothing
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your enum has multiple values with the same underlying value, it may appear to not change:

```
public enum MyEnum {
    One = 1,
    Two = 1,
}
```

Here, you'd only ever see `One`. Similarly, a flag enumeration like:

```
[Flags]
public enum MyEnum {
    One = 1,
    Two = 2,
    All = One | Two,
}
```

You'd never see `All`, just `One | Two`.