# Reassignment to Enum variable not working

Tags: c#, enums, variable-assignment

I have a static variable of an enum type inside one class.

```
public enum SomeEnum
{
    UnwantedValue,
    DesiredValue
}

public class SomeClass
{
    public static SomeEnum Variable;
    ...
}
```

I want to reassign the variable elsewhere, but for whatever reason the assignment has no effect on its value.

```
public class OtherClass
{
    public OtherClass()
    {
        // SomeClass.Variable defaults to SomeEnum.UnwantedValue

        SomeClass.Variable = SomeEnum.DesiredValue;

        // SomeClass.Variable still equals SomeEnum.UnwantedValue
    }

    public void Foo()
    {
        SomeClass.Variable = SomeEnum.DesiredValue;
        // This does not work either
    }
}
```

Explicitly assigning the values of the enum has no effect.

```
public enum SomeEnum
{
    UnwantedValue = 0,
    DesiredValue = 1
}
```

Assigning a value to the variable at initialization is the only time assignment works, but I still can not change the value elsewhere.

```
public static SomeEnum Variable = SomeEnum.DesiredValue;
```

I am at a loss for why I can not reassign the value of this variable.

EDIT: Changing the variable to an instance type allows me to reassign its value like usual.

```
public SomeEnum Variable; // This fixes the problem
```

However, this is unfeasible, as it is being used in a singleton class and needs to be kept static (in case someone wants to call me out on my need for a singleton, the class is meant to handle contention for a system resource across the entire application; the enum type is used as a flag for the status of the resource).

[NOTE: I referred to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6834441/what-could-cause-an-assignment-to-not-work), but it did not explain why the variable can not be reassigned.]

Comment: Is your code multi-threaded or single-threaded?

Comment: How are you testing it doesn't work?

Comment: It sounds strange. Are the two classes in different assemblies (projects)? How do you check if your assignments "work" or not?

Comment: If `SomeEnum` is in assembly A, and `OtherClass` is in assembly B, be sure to force a re-compilation of B after you edit the enum in A.

Comment: Try reducing your problem to a small but *complete* example that exhibits the problem - I'm unable to reproduce your issue given the code that you've presented.

Comment: ***a)*** This is why fields should never be public. Change it do a property with a backing field and put a breakpoint in it. ***b)*** should it really be static? Each time you create a new instance of `OtherClass` the field will be resetted to the original value.

Comment: The only way I can come *close* to this behaviour is if `SomeClass` is generic, `OtherClass` is specifying one type (e.g. `SomeClass<int>`), and you're checking the value afterwards using a different type (e.g. `SomeClass<long>`). With generics, statics are per-type.

Comment: This is all in the same assembly and namespace. The only difference between the code samples I gave and my actual code is the names of things. There are currently no other references to this enum type or the variable that uses it.

Comment: @SergRogovtsev After tracing this code all the way up the stack, I found that it is being run at the initialization of our top-level Form element (i.e. application startup). There is no explicit multi-threading, but perhaps Windows Forms implicitly runs initialization of the UI in a different thread from the rest of the application.

Comment: @CalMlynarczyk Are you sure `SomeClass` is not generic?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to answer this since the code you're showing is not the exact code you are having problems with. I have a feeling some piece is missing here. Still, this might help make things more cleare:

Try creating the methods `SetSomeEnum()` and `GetSomeEnum()` in the class containing the enum, and make the enum itself private. This should, strictly speaking, not make any difference in the logic. It should however make debugging easier as you will be able to step through and see more clearly which calls are being made, etc.

```
private static SomeEnum _myEnum;

public static void SetSomeEnum(SomeEnum value){
    _myEnum = value;
}

public static SomeEnum SetSomeEnum(SomeEnum value){
    return _myEnum;
}
```

**Edit:** On second thought, a Property is probably preferable here:

```
public SomeEnum MyEnum
{
    get { return _myEnum }
    set { _myEnum = value; }
}
```